# Symfony 3 - Builder form - Filter Select by Select?

Tags: forms, symfony, select, many-to-many, symfony-2.3

I need help with form management on Symfony 3.

---

- **the action** : Use the "category" entity to filter another
  Entity "subcategory" in a single form. A precision
  The "Category" entity is linked by a ManyToMany relationship to
  The "Subcategory" entity.
- **View** : When I select the category of my choice in the first
  Select, the second select only proposes to me the subcategories of
  This one.

---

I have to use Ajax, by the Form Builder or Twig filters. I can not find a clean and simple way, so I appeal to your help.

Comment: Hi @Morgan and welcome to SO! Please read the guide on how to ask questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to answer your question - it needs to be written in English :)

Comment: It's done. Sorry

Comment: No worries. Do you have some code you could show us? What have you tried so far? What I would do is to customize the rendering of the `Sub Category` field and attach `Select2` to it. There are also bundles which could help use the `select2` field faster in your form.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually not too complicated although you will need an AJAX request. You don't need a real form for this part because you are not interested in the main-category that has been selected but only in the sub-category. Most times you want to perform some action if the sub-category has been chosen but there are plenty possibilities for that, so i just give you a push forwards:

```
// controller

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="my_action")
     */
    public function myAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $categories = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAll();

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'categories' => $categories,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/subcategories", name="ajax_subcategories")
     */
    public function ajaxSubCategoriesAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $category = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($request->get('id'));

        if(null === $category )
        {
            return new Response('');
        }

        $options = '';

        foreach($category->getSubCategories() as $subCategory)
        {
            $options .= '<option value="'.$subCategory->getId().'">'.$subCategory->getName().'</option>';
        }

        return new Response($options);
    }
}
```

and the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>My page</h1>

    <select id="category">
        {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <select id="subCategory">
        {% if categories|length %}
            {% for subCategory in categories[0].subCategories %}
                <option value="{{ subCategory.id }}">{{ subCategory.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </select>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#category').change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ path('ajax_subcategories') }}',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {"id":$(this).val()},
                    success: function(data) { 
                        $('#subCategory').html(data);
                        alert('SubCategory selected: ' + $('#subCategory').val());
                        // Now do something else
                    }
                });
            });
            $('#subCategory').change(function() {
                alert('SubCategory selected: ' + $(this).val());
                // Now do something else
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```